# Let $S(V)$ be the set of all subspaces of a given vector space $V$...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $S(V)$ be the set of all subspaces of a given vector space $V$ and define operations $+$, $\cdot$ on $S(V)$ so that for $W_1, W_2 \in S(V)$ the sum $W_1+W_2$ has its standard meaning and $cW_1 = \{cw \mid w \in W_1\}$ for $c \in \Bbb R$.  Is the set $S(V)$, equipped with these operations, a vector space? Explain why or why not.

Vector space needs to have the $0$ vector, closed under addition and scalar multiplication.  How do I show all three, especially closed under addition?

Comment: When $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$, is $W_1+W_2$ a subspace of $V$? If yes, then $S(V)$ is closed under addition.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The zero subspace $0=\{0\}\subset V$ behaves as an additive identity: $W+0=0+W=W$ for any $W\in S(V)$. But given $W\in S(V)$ can you find an additive inverse $U\in S(V)$ such that $W+U=0$?